# Markov model software

Tags: windows, cross-platform, statistics

I have been searching for a software that I can use where I can input transitional probabilities, observational probabilities for a Markov Model and begin determining the probability of observing sequences. I placed an example of data I work with regularly and I am looking for a Markov model software that can utilise it to give me probabilities.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: is the double A probability related to double A in the sequence (if not why not use a different variable)? I've created Markov Chains but am not familiar with observation probabilities equation/syntax. Can you explain it/what P(char|#) means?

Comment: @depperm Thanks for the reply. It means there two different states A which is why we cannot have a different variable.

Comment: how is it supposed to keep the `A`s separate? why not A1 and A2? In the observation probabilities how is P(B|1) = 0 when the initial prob is .2?

Comment: You may also want to check out the https://quant.stackexchange.com/ since such models are used in finance too.